# AMQPRuntimeException with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, connection, server, php-amqplib

I have WordPress 4.1.1 and when I try to create or update a post I get the following error:

`PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException thrown 
Error Connecting to server(111): Connection refused`

It happens on my prod server, but not on local.

Someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: are you using the default guest:guest user in production? If yes, that user can only connect to localhost